# '504 - Gateway Timeout' when Indexing the items in Episerver Find

Tags: episerver, episerver-find

When Indexing the items, it fails **sometimes** and it gives,

```
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout. [The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.]
```

The Indexing logic is here as below,

```cs
var client = EPiServer.Find.Framework.SearchClient.Instance;
List<ItemModel> items = getItems(); // Get more than 1000 items
List<ItemModel> tempItems = new List<ItemModel>();

//Index 50 items at a time
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tempItems.Add(item);
    if (tempItems.Count == 50)
    {
        client.Index(tempItems);
        tempItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

What causes this to happen ?

*Note: The above mentioned* `ItemModel` *is a custom model which is not implemented interfaces (such as* `IContent`*). And the* `items` *is a list of* `ItemModel` *objects.*

*Additional info:

EPiServer.Find.Framework version 13.0.1

EPiServer.CMS.Core version 11.9.2*

Comment: We've experienced this too. Does it happen for development or production indexes? Either way, in a few cases we've had to switch to indexes in a different cluster.

Comment: It happens in Production indexes. And it might happen in the development index too.

Comment: You are probably better off submitting a support ticket to Episerver about it.

Comment: Episerver Find performance is not very excellent (our company has several projects involving Find). Occasional timeouts are quite normal for it. If they cause problems for you I would contact Episerver support like Ted suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I always figured the `SearchClient` to be a bit sketchy when **manipulating** data in Find, as far as I figured (but I have to check this) the SearchClient obey under the request limitation of Episerver Find and when doing bigger operations in loops it tends to time out.

Instead, use the `ContentIndexer`, i.e.

```cs
// Use this or injected parameter
var loader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();

// Remove all children or not
var cascade = true;

ContentReference entryPoint = ...where you want to start

// Get all indexable languages from Find
Languages languages = SearchClient.Instance.Settings.Languages;

// Remove all current instances of all languages below the selected content node
//languages.ForEach(x => ContentIndexer.Instance.RemoveFromIndex(entryPoint, cascade.Checked, x.FieldSuffix));

foreach (var lang in languages)
{
    if (cascade)
    {
        var descendents = loader.GetDescendents(entryPoint);

        foreach (ContentReference descendent in descendents)
        {
            ContentIndexer.Instance.RemoveFromIndex(descendent, false, lang.FieldSuffix);
        }
    }

    // Try delete the entrypoint
    var entryTest = loader.Get<IContent>(entryPoint, new CultureInfo(lang.FieldSuffix));
    if (entryTest != null)
    {
        var delRes = ContentIndexer.Instance.Delete(entryTest);
    }
}
```

This is the most bulletproof way to delete stuff from the index as far as I figured.

Comment: @Erik, We are using a custom model (in this case it's `ItemModel`) for the indexing entity. which not implements `IContent`. In that case, is this `ContentIndexer` useful?

Comment: I assume the ItemModel is a custom object?

Comment: Yes. And the `items` is having a List of `ItemModel` objects.

Comment: Please update your question that this regards custom objects not inheriting from IContent. Anyway, in that case you need to throttle your requests accordingly to your find license capacity so you don't overload the SearchClient.

Comment: I have updated (*added the info as a note*). And thanks for your view regarding this :)